# Hide View when scrolling RecyclerView (Not hiding the toolbar)

Tags: android

I have the following Layout and I want to hide the LinearLayout "cv" and its included child behind the toolbar.

I searched for it and found a lot of Examples to hide the toolbar, but none of them showed me to hide any other View than the toolbar ([example](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/)). Is there a possibility to do it with a CoordinatorLayout?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.app.activities.AccountDetail">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

        <include layout="@layout/single_account" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cv">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```